# Using segues in storyboard make a view controller that has non optional properties?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

I have a view controller which has a property.

```
class GameVC: UIViewController {

    var game:Game?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

For the view controller to make any sense it has to have a game property. For this reason I want the property not to be optional (I'd also prefer not to have to unwrap it when I use it the whole way through).

I'm currently overriding prepare for segue in the VC before this one and setting the game property. This is because I want to definitely be using segues and storyboards. Is there anyway I can make this view controller have a custom init and still use segues and storyboards?

Comment: You can't use a custom init, but you can make the property an implicitly unwrapped optional: `var game: Game!`.  This way you won't have to unwrap it before using it, but it will crash if you try to use it before it is set non-nil value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have two choices:

Initialize in the declaration:

```
class GameVC: UIViewController {
     let game = Game()
```

Implement `init(coder:)` or `awakeFromNib`:

```
class GameVC: UIViewController {
     let game : Game
     required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         self.game = Game()
         super.init(coder:aDecoder)
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion there is no good way for dependency injection when using storyboards. I think that storyboards are against object oriented design principles. For software development in a team I wouldn't recommend to use them, except for prototyping.

Instead, I use simple xib files and try to make the screens (aka UIViewControllers) as independent as possible. I also implement navigation between screens in own wireframe classes to separate the animated navigation from the main purpose of the UIViewController (constructing/managing the view tree). Then it's possible to inject the necessary objects without completely loosing the benefits of using interface builder.

Example:

```
final class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    convenience override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        self.init()
    }

    convenience required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.init()
    }

    convenience init() {
        fatalError("Not supported!")
    }

    init(viewModel: ViewModel, wireframe: Wireframe) {
        self.viewModel = viewModel
        self.wireframe = wireframe
        super.init(nibName: "MyViewController", bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)))
    }

    private let viewModel: ViewModel
    private let wireframe: Wireframe

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // do something with viewModel
    }

    @IBAction func close() {
        wireframe.close()
    }

}

let wireframe: Wireframe = ConcreteWireframe()
let viewModel: ViewModel = ConcreteViewModel()
let screen: UIViewController = MyViewController(viewModel: viewModel, wireframe: wireframe)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, Storyboard (and XIB files) use [`init?(coder:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621403-init) to instantiate elements, you can't pass additional parameters to this init.

Common practice is using implicit unwrapped optionals:

```
var game:Game!
```

This way, you can use it like a non-optional property, and it will crash on runtime if not set before used.

If you set this property in [`prepare(for:sender:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621490-prepare) it will be ready in `viewDidLoad`, so it can be used safely.

Comment: Agreed, but it will need to be an optional, or the compiler will force you to assign a value to it in your init method(s).

Comment: @DuncanC  It is an implicitly unwrapped optional, so you do not need to assign a value in init

Answer (score 0):

In my apps, I just use something like

`var game = Game()`

That way it will never be `nil` and I can set the value before I segue.